# Tkinter entry not getting the gender

Tags: csv, tkinter

Hello I have some data in a CSV and I want to make a gender printing Tkinter program

the problem is I don't have any idea about that so can someone tell, me how to make a gender Tkinter program using a radio button.. here's my script what i tried pls tell how to extend for functionality

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
gender = tk.IntVar()
radiobutton_1 = tk.Radiobutton(app, text='Male', variable=gender, value=1)
radiobutton_1.grid(row=0, column=4)
radiobutton_2 = tk.Radiobutton(app, text='Female', variable=gender, value=2)
radiobutton_2.grid(row=0, column=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please Help Guys::

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please have a read at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , this can improve your chances to get help. Good luck.